# beanio Repeating segments without any child field component must have minOccurs=maxOccurs

Tags: xml, xslt, jaxb

Have not used BeanIO alot. Am trying to read in a simple list of strings from a CSV file like so:
AA11
BB22
CC33A
4D33L

The most trivial of examples at beanio.org uses an object with fields. I don't need that. All i want is to read in just strings.

**What I have**
**1. XSLT coupon.xml**

```
<beanio xmlns="http://www.beanio.org/2012/03">
    <stream name="coupons" format="csv">
        <parser>
            <property name="delimiter" value="," />
            <property name="lineSeparator" value="\n" />
            <property name="whitespaceAllowed" value="true" />
        </parser>       
        <record name="header" class="map" maxOccurs="1">            
            <field name="recordType" rid="true" literal="H" />                  
            <field name="fileDate" type="date" format="yyyy-MM-dd" />
        </record>
        <record name="detail" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" class="java.lang.String" />       
    </stream>
</beanio>
```

**2. CouponProcessor.java**

```
public class CouponProcessor {

    public Map<String, Boolean> readCouponCodesFromCSV(InputStream couponCsv) throws Exception {        
        StreamFactory factory = StreamFactory.newInstance();        
        factory.loadResource("/coupon_codes/coupon.xml"); // ** Problem occurs here **        
        BeanReader in = factory.createReader("coupons", new InputStreamReader(couponCsv));           

        Object record = null;
        Map<String, Boolean> couponCodeMap = new TreeMap<>();

        while ((record = in.read()) != null) {
            switch (in.getRecordName()) {
            case "header" : 
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                Map<String, Object> header = (Map<String,Object>) record;
                log.info(header.get("fileDate"));
                break;
            case "detail" :
                String code = (String) record;              
                couponCodeMap.put(code, couponCodeMap.get(code) == null ? Boolean.FALSE : Boolean.TRUE); // False='unique', True='duplicate'
            }            
        }        
        in.close();        
        return couponCodeMap;
    }
}
```

**3. Problem being encountered**
A this line

```
factory.loadResource("/coupon_codes/coupon.xml");
```

Am getting the following error:

```
CouponProcessor.readCouponCodesFromCSV(java.io.InputStream) throws java.lang.Exception: javax.ejb.EJBException: org.beanio.BeanIOConfigurationException: Invalid record 'detail', in stream 'coupons': Repeating segments without any child field component must have minOccurs=maxOccurs
```

**4. Questions**
Q1. With beanio is it possible to map primitives/wrappers and Strings without user-defined objects?
Q2. What is causing the problem above?
Q3. How can this problem be fixed? What is the most befitting solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Have gone round the problem to just use Scanner class (in the mean time) like so:

Comment: Have gone round the problem to just use Scanner class and Apache commons-io FileUtils class (in the mean time) like so:<br> 
'FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(csvStream, tempFile);
Scanner scan = new Scanner(tempFile);
Map<String, Boolean> couponCodeMap = new HashMap<>();
while (scan.hasNext()) {
 String couponCode = scan.nextLine();          
 couponCodeMap.put(couponCode, couponCodeMap.get(couponCode)== null ? Boolean.FALSE : Boolean.TRUE);
}'
<br>But as the input csv scales a library like beanio will definitely become inevitable.